# Sharing an Access database on the web without using Sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-access

Is there any way to have an Access database shared on the web that does not involve using Sharepoint? I have been looking to figure out if this is a possibility or not.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean shared on the web?

I think Office365 has a net version of Access 2010, called Access Services.

You can always hook it up to a web app front end, in whatever tool you know how to program in.